# google distance matrix api strange

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance

I am facing a strange problem here,

when I run below url from web browser or from java command line

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=416%2063,Sweden&destinations=424%2069,Stor%C3%A5s%20Industrigatan%2020,Angered,G%C3%B6teborg&sensor=false

I get below results.

```
{
  "destination_addresses" : [ "Storås Industrigata 20, 424 69
Angered, Sweden" ],
  "origin_addresses" : [ "Gothenburg, Sweden" ],
  "rows" : [
     {
        "elements" : [
           {
              "distance" : {
                 "text" : "10.4 km",
                 "value" : 10388
              },
              "duration" : {
                 "text" : "15 mins",
                 "value" : 924
              },
              "status" : "OK"
           }
       ]
     }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

but when I run the same url from glassfish server I mean sending an
http request from
form submit I get below strange response

```
{ "destination_addresses" : [ "" ],
  "origin_addresses" : [ "Gothenburg, Sweden" ],
  "rows" : [
     {
        "elements" : [
           {
              "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
           }
        ]
     }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

please not destination_addresses is empty in this case and status in
NOT_FOUND.

Java code I used to get the response is

```
private String getResponse(String URL) throws Exception {
        InputStream stream = new URL(URL).openStream();
        byte[] array = new byte[stream.available()];
        stream.read(array);
        return new String(array);
}
```

please guide me to resolve this issue,

thanks....

Comment: Show us your code, preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader or Crystal Ball.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/133242)

Comment: I have edited the question, strange thing is the code gives expected result when I run through a main method in the class but when I run the same method using a html form submission (lets say inside a servlet) response was NOT_FOUND

Comment: thats http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=416%2063,Sweden&destinations=424%2069,Stor%C3%A5s%20Industrigatan%2020,Angered,G%C3%B6teborg&sensor=false

Comment: URL already mentioned on the question

Comment: The problem is obviously the URL you are actually using in your servlet. My money is on that it's not encoded properly after you get it from the form request. Add some logging, debug your servlet.

Comment: but same url runs when I use main method in the class

Comment: You're missing the point. The URL you *think* is being used *isn't* because it's not encoded properly.

Comment: yeah you are correct, url encoded is not correct, thanks you guys

Answer (score 0):

Use https 
unless google will not let your software to connect.

and
get a api key.

read this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=416%2063,Sweden&destinations=424%2069,Stor%C3%A5s%20Industrigatan%2020,Angered,G%C3%B6teborg&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

be sure to replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual API key

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using the Distance Matrix API in Java. Setting the language in my request seems to make it work:

```
    DistanceMatrixElement distanceMatrixElement;
    DistanceMatrix matrix;

    try
    {
        matrix = distanceMatrixApiRequest
                .origins(...)
                .destinations(...)
                .language("en")
                .await();
    }
```